# Javascript Files Priority on document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Is it important to call JavaScript files in the order that they are needed when we use document ready for inline script functions?

For example, imagine I want to call jQuery's counter-up plugin under jQuery Waypoints. It's required to load jQuery, Waypoints and finally the counter-up script respectively in the header of the document and to call `counterup()` in an inline script as below:

```js
    <script>
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 1000
        });
    </script>
```

What happens if I call that function under `$(document).ready` and move script import statements to the bottom of `<body>`?

Is it needed to call the required files at the bottom of body respectively? (eg. import jquery.min.js at the end of all other libraries.)

Comment: If the import of `jquery`, ... is below any of the script that use try use jQuery at the time it is evaluated, then it will fail. e.g. if you would would place your example code inside a `$(document).ready`, it would still require that `jQuery` is included before. If you place it in a  callback that is called by a `setTimeout` it might work if the `jQuery` is loaded within that time.

Comment: @RGraham question you pointed is about priority of inline scripts. But I asked about priority of linked javascript files that required for that inline scripts. Are they equal?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` Will throw a Reference Error if jQuery is not defined before (i.e. if jquery.min.js is not imported before `$` is evaluated).

So you have to first add a `<script>` tag with jquery before the `<script>` with your custom code, which should be, by the way, in a seperate file.

Then, since `<script>` can modify the DOM, the "DOM ready" event will not be fired until all the JS files are downloaded and evaluated and executed, even if you put them outside of the `<html>` tag.

That being said, if (and only if) your code with the plugins are all inside the "domready" callback, you can add your script tag with the plugins after your custom code, like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.tooltipster/2.1.4/css/tooltipster.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test" title="Beautiful tooltip plugin!">Hello world!</div>
</body>
  </html>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
      $("#test").tooltipster();
      console.log('Test OK');
    });

  </script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.tooltipster/2.1.4/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
```

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dapimuquveki/1)

Comment: Just for completeness: A `script` tag has to be a descendant of `head` or `body`. If it is a child of `html` or even outside of `html` it would be invalid html, and the browsers is then required to fixed it. About the ready event: There might be exceptions where scripts are marked as `async` or `defer`, or when the loading and execution of scripts is suppressed/delayed by previous included scripts.